# Define sample rates on ALSA

Tags: audio, alsa

There is a way to define a set of sample rates to be used on one ALSA audio device?

Looks than my current kernel has some bug that can be patched with this:

https://github.com/LibreELEC/LibreELEC.tv/blob/e1f33a285b884e5d4d713b8e1cbbb8ea392747ae/packages/linux/patches/aarch64/linux-007-sound_soc_aml_m8-Report-only-working-frequecies-and-bit-depths.patch

It define a set of valid sample rates

```
#define STUB_RATES  SNDRV_PCM_RATE_44100 | SNDRV_PCM_RATE_48000 | SNDRV_PCM_RATE_88200 | SNDRV_PCM_RATE_96000 | SNDRV_PCM_RATE_176400 | SNDRV_PCM_RATE_192000
#define STUB_FORMATS    SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S16_LE | SNDRV_PCM_FMTBIT_S32_LE
```

But there is a way to get the same result using ALSA configuration?

I know that is posible to force a sample rate like this:

```
pcm.device{
    format S24_LE
    rate 96000
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}
```

But is possible to define a list of sample rates?